# Alternating Midpoint/Trapezoidal Rule Approximations

Tags: calculus

Suppose we are to measure the area under $f$ in the interval $[a,b]$. We are to make approximations with $n$ regions, using the Midpoint and Trapezoidal rules, for $n = 1, 2, 3, \cdots$.

Is there a function $f$ such that for all odd $n$, the Midpoint Rule is a strictly better approximation than the Trapezoidal Rule, and for even $n$ the Trapezoidal rule is strictly better?

Comment: Where does this come from? Just curious...

Comment: Does $f$ have to be continuous?

Comment: @vonbrand I saw a thread on reddit that showed the two methods, and I wondered if there was a case where they alternated in closeness of approximation.

Comment: @Henry I would hope so, but I guess that's not necessary. I think one could just define the points of a function with what would the "even" points on the function, and not define the odd ones (or similar).

Comment: My thought was that the "trapezoidal points" include $a$ and $b$ while the "midpoints" never do, so you could do something clever there